# Phonegap-Cordova / Why doesn't my image appear?

Tags: html, iphone, image, cordova

I have a cordova application (equivalent to phonegap) displaying an image like so:

```
<img src="../assets/images/logos/mylogo.png" alt ="" />
```

The arborescence uses by cordova is:

-index.html
 -assets (has no parent folder)
      --images
       ---logos
        -----mylogo.png
 -scripts
      --1dc45af27.myapp.js  //this is inside that my img src is declared

This works well on desktop, web mobile (yes my app works on every device), but not on the cordova app running on iOS.

Despite of the relative path, the image doesn't appear, just a square.

Any idea?

**-----UPDATE** 
I tried with the server on the port 8000 (`cordova serve`) and it well displays the logo when I use: `../assets/images/logos/mylogo.png`, however on the iOS device, it doesn't show the logo...

it only works when I do:

```
src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/10434B65-E6C2-4442-9AFE-9ADE1A5A53E1/myApp.app/www/assets/images/logos/logo-wealcome.png"
```

Comment: Where is the first/main HTML file (index.html) file located? If the file is on the Device then all subsequent request will be trying to locate the file in the phone and not on the webserver. Also you have mentioned it works on **web mobile** do you mean to say Web App?

Comment: @frank Yes it's a webapp. Actually, all my html templates (except `index.html` of course) are concatenated and compressed into `1dc45af27.myapp.js`. That's why I tried `../assets/images/logos/mylogo.png`. The expected absolute path is: `/ios/www/assets/images/logos/mylogo.png`, how to reference it relatively?

Comment: I am assuming that the main/landing(index.html) file is located on the phone in the `www` directory. To load the image you need to change the src attribute as `src=assets/images/logos/logo-wealcome.png`. Please not that the `www` directory becomes the base directory for your application.

Comment: If it was so simple, I wouldn t ask the question ;) The thing is that all my JS are compressed so tht each Angular module are declared in /page/mymodule ( and the img is declared within it).  Note the "/" before page that causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="./assets/images/logos/mylogo.png" alt ="" />`

remove a single "." on your src?